# HTML tag to select Flash-player plugin to play flv

Tags: html, video-streaming, flash

If I have .flv files on my server at some location like http://www.example.com/archive/test.flv. In HTML page how can I tell the browser to use Flash player to play this video like youtube videos are played.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

PS: I am noober than noob in web dev, so please give some code snippet or answers that beginners like me can understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create or find an existing video player SWF; there is no built-in Flash video player.  I've found [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) to work pretty well.

**Update:**

Here's a sample of how you can embed the JW Player:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var flashvars = { file:'yourvideofile.flv',autostart:'true' };
      var params = { allowfullscreen:'true', allowscriptaccess:'always' };
      var attributes = { id:'player1', name:'player1' };

      swfobject.embedSWF('player.swf','player','480','270','9.0.115','false',
        flashvars, params, attributes);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="player"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I am noober than noob in web dev and didn't get your answer completely, so can you please provide a code snippet showing how to do that? Your help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Unfortunately, it's more than a code snippet you'll need.  First, you need to download a video player SWF (try searching for those keywords).  Then, add that SWF to your web site.  Then, you can embed the SWF in your page, adding a parameter to let the player SWF know where the video is located.

Comment: Yes.  And unfortunately, there is no small snippet option for this.  How you embed the SWF depends on which SWF you end up using.  I'll try to put together a sample for you, but you may be better off looking at the sample documentation in the site @ngduc linked to; at that site, you can download a player and see samples of how to use it.

Comment: Great, That does the trick. This is exactly what I was looking for ;) 
1000 Up votes if SO allowed... Thanks a ton Jacob \m/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one to make a player for your flv file:

http://oos.moxiecode.com/flvplayer/

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have Dreamweaver, you can embed an flv video in a few seconds (it handles the embedding the associated code and resources.)

If not, you can find nice flash video players for download (free or paid) by googling. For instance, here's an option that offers free and paid alternatives:
[Flow player](http://flowplayer.org/)

And, additionally, you could upload the video to youtube and just embed the code on your site for playing, too.